Mapping between generalized forces and external torque of a rigid body whose rotation is described by quaternion is not unique(?)
In this paper the mapping between generalized forces and external torques for a rigid body (when the rotation is described by a quaternion) is derived:
$$\textit{F}_Q = 2\textbf{G}^TT'$$
where $\textit{F}_Q$ is a vector of generalized forces (quaternion elements as generalized coordinates) and $T'$ is a vector of external torque and $\textbf{G}$ is the matrix that maps between those two
$$G = \begin{bmatrix}-Q_1 & Q_0 & Q_3 & -Q_2\\ -Q_2&-Q_3& Q_0& Q_1 \\ -Q_3& Q_2& -Q_1& Q_0\end{bmatrix}.$$
I have derived a vector of generalized forces, I mapped it to a vector of external torques, which works correctly. However, when I mapped the external torques back to generalized forces, the generalized forces were different. Does that mean that this mapping is not unique and different generalized forces in terms of quaternion can rotation represent the same external torques applied to a rigid body?
Edit:
I am creating a biomechanical model. My Equations of motion (for 1 joint) are:
$$\textbf{M}(Q)\dot{q}=f(q)$$
where $q = (Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z)^T$, $\textbf{M}(Q)$ is joint-space mass matrix and $f(q)$ are the external forces ($\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, $\omega_z$ are angular velocities).
To add a contribution of muscle force to the equations of motion, I calculate the muscle length $l_m = f(Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3)$, then I calculate the $4 \times 1$ jacobian $J_Q$ w.r.t. the quaternion coordinates
$$J_Q = \frac{\partial l_m(\textbf{Q})}{\partial Q_i} $$
from this I calculate $3 \times 1$ vector of external torques
$$\tau_E = \frac{1}{2} G J_Q F_m$$
where $F_m$ is a scalar muscle force. Then I can finish my equations of motion:
$$
\textbf{M}(Q)\dot{q}=f(q)+
\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{0}^{4 \times 1} \\
\tau_E^{3 \times 1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and it works perfectly. For some reason I need to map the $3 \times 1$ external torque back to $4 \times 1$ generalized forces (if I can call it this way). And this mapping back doesn't give the same forces as the one calculated by using the jacobian of muscle lengths.

„However, when I mapped the external torques back to generalized forces“ which equation you use ?
the determinate of $~\mathbf G,\mathbf G^T=0~$, thus you can't solve the equation for $~\mathbf T'~$ ?

That is not a square matrix. There should be some degrees of freedom not pinned down. This problem is particularly well-described in geometric algebra; in fact, I think I recognise that matrix as a truncated version of what is happening in the Kustaanheimo-Stiefel transformation that maps a Hydrogen atom problem to the QHO. There is a gauge freedom involved.

$\textbf{G}\textbf{G}^T = \textbf{I}$, but the determinate of $\textbf{G}^T\textbf{G} = 0$. Well quaternion is 4 degrees of freedom to describe 3 rotations but the quaternion must be unit which removes 1 dof. Here there are 4 generalized forces to describe 3 external torques but without any constraint (?) so maybe there might be a problem.

not clear for me did you used the Euler equation  $ ~\mathbf I,\mathbf{\dot{\omega}}+\omega\times,\mathbf I,\omega=\mathbf \tau_{\rm{E}}~$ is $~M(Q)~$ invertible ?

The final equations of motion are large as there are 4 spherical joints, I used Kane's method to solve the equations of motion. $M(Q)$ is invertible, but I plan to solve the simulation using implicit solvers.

please see my comment how to simulate

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
Starting with the Euler equations
$$ \b I\,\b{\dot{\omega}}+\omega\times\,\b I\,\omega=\b\tau_{\rm{E}}\tag 1$$
with
$$\omega=2\,\b Q\,\b{\dot{z}}\tag 2$$
where
$$\b Q= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} -b&a&-d&c\\ -c&d&a&-b
\\ -d&-c&b&a\end {array} \right] \quad
\b{\dot{z}}= \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{a} \\
   \dot{b} \\
   \dot{c} \\
   \dot{d} \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
the constraint equation for the quaternions is:
$$   a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\quad, 
a\,\dot a+b\,\dot b+c\,\dot c+d\,\dot d=0$$
from here you obtain
$$ \b{\dot{z}}= \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{a} \\
   \dot{b} \\
   \dot{c} \\
   \dot{d} \\
 \end{bmatrix}= \underbrace{\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -{\frac {b}{a}}&-{\frac {c}{a}}&-{\frac {d
}{a}}\\1&0&0\\ 0&1&0
\\0&0&1\end {array} \right] }_{\b T}
\,\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{b} \\
   \dot{c} \\
   \dot{d} \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b{\dot{q}}}
$$
hence equation (2)
$$\omega=\underbrace{2\,\b Q\,\b T}_{\b J (3\times 3)}\,\b{\dot{q}}$$
the generalize torque is:
$$\b\tau_G=\b J^T\b\tau_E\quad, 
\b\tau_E=\left(\b J^T\right)^{-1}\b\tau_G$$

the determinate of $~\b J~$ is equal to $~\frac 8a~$
how to simulate
from the constraint equation
\begin{align*}
&\dot{a}=-\frac{1}{a}\,(b+c+d)
\end{align*}
and with  $~\omega=\b J\,\b{\dot{q}}~$ you obtain
\begin{align*}
 &\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{b} \\
    \dot{c} \\
    \dot{d} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 =\frac 12\,\begin{bmatrix}
                a & d & -c \\
                -d & a & b \\
                c & -b & a \\
              \end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}
                               \omega_x \\
                               \omega_y \\
                               \omega_z \\
                             \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
those are 4 first order  differential equations for the quaternions.
additional form equation (1) you obtain 3 first order  differential equations  for the angular velocity $~\b \omega~$
so altogether 7 first order differential equation. notice that the initial conditions must fellfield the constraint equation $~a(0)^2+b(0)^2+c(0)^2+d(0)^2=1~$ and also you have to check it during the simulation
$~a(t)^2+b(t)^2+c(t)^2+d(t)^2=1~$
the rotation matrix between body system and inertial system
is a function of the quaternions
\begin{align*}
 &\b S= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {a}^{2}+{b}^{2}-{c}^{2}-{d}^{2}&2\,bc+2\,a
d&2\,bd-2\,ac\\ 2\,bc-2\,ad&{a}^{2}+{c}^{2}-{d}^{2}-
{b}^{2}&2\,cd+2\,ab\\ 2\,bd+2\,ac&2\,cd-2\,ab&{a}^{2
}+{d}^{2}-{b}^{2}-{c}^{2}\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}

This seems like a nice approach. However, now you get 3 generalized torques for 4 generalized coordinates (of the quaternion). How do I interpret this ?

That makes sense, I always didn't know if I can call the quaternion coordinates generalized coordinates. However I am not exactly sure how I would use this solution to my problem. I tried to edit my question si it gives insight into my problem.

I will add the equations to do the dynamic simulation

Thanks, whis will help with the simulation. However, my inital problem was somewhat different. Normally I would calculate the muscle lengths and then jacobian, multiplied it by muscle force and map it to external torques. However, I have muscle lengths and muscle lengths jacobians using Euler angles (those are exported from somewhere), which I need to map into muscle lengths and muscle lengths jacobians using quaternions. It is because I am doing a polynomial fitting of these lengths and moment arms to get continuous function. I hope you understood.

The problem is not about simulating the system. It is more about "preprocessing" the muscle lengths to obtain the external torques using quaternion that are equivalent to the external torques using euler angles.

in your equation , you didn't used the constraint equation ?

Which equation do you mean now ?

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$

Oh I understand. Now it's working perfectly, thank you very much !

Can I have one more question ? When I now calculate the exact muscle lengths using the constraint equation, the length depends on the sign of a quaternion. That means that at some point of the simulation the muscle lengths get wrong, but multiplying the quaternion by -1 corrects the muscle length. The old calculation I used didn't have this problem. Is there some kind of solution to this problem ? I don't necessarily need to fix it because now I will be approximating the muscle lengths by polynomials, I was just wonering. Thank you one more time

I will try. I didn't get this problem for euler angles and for the first solution using quaternion with this equation $$\tau_E = \frac{1}{2} G J_Q F_m$$ - in this solution I derived muscle lengths without the constraint equation.

at each step the simulation, you should do this calculation $~z\mapsto \dfrac{z}{\sqrt{z^T,  z}}~$ this is also valid for negative z.  you first used the Euler angels instead of the quaternion, did you got also sign problem?.  If it work with negative sign it’s o.k .

I mean, it is valid for the negative z but I don't see how this changes the quaternion, the denominator is always 1. The muscle gets wrong when most of the quaternion elements are negative (not strictly all of them), when this happens, multiplying the quaternion by -1 corrects the muscle lengths.

To try to help you, I have to look at your equations. Can you put it in Google Drive ?

I am dealing with it symbolically in Matlab, if that is ok ?

can you use also MAPLE ? I just have OCTAVE I am not sure if your source will be o.k

I tried to do some testing and it seems the length is correct only when the $w$ element is positive number (so only for positive rotations). During the simulation if you check for $w$ and multiply the quaternion by $-1$ when $w$ is negative, it works. There is a singularity when $w = 0$ but that obviously comes from the constraint. Unfortunately I don't have Maple but I think I figured out the solution but the sign thing still feels weird to me.

Here I copied the equtions already derived. But when writing this, I realized that the problem is because of the constraint and how I used it to build to muscle length equation.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byw3u18bN7Tinze20HOHacHZaS4NShNp/view?usp=sharing

lets move to the chatting room

Yes that is a good idea
